# How to get lines that don't contain certain patterns

Tags: linux, parsing, awk, grep, filefilter

I have a file that contain many lines :

```
ABRD0455252003666
JLKS8568875002886
KLJD2557852003625
.
.
.
AION9656532007525
BJRE8242248007866
```

I want to extract the lines that start with (ABRD or AION) and in column 12 to 14 the numbers (003 or 007).

The output should be

```
KLJD2557852003625
BJRE8242248007866
```

I have tried this and it works but it s too long command and I want to optimise it for performance concerns:

```
 egrep  -a --text '^.{12}(?:003|007)' file.txt > result.txt |touch results.txt && chmod 777 results.txt |egrep -v -a --text  "ABRD|AION" result.txt > result2.text
```

Comment: `^(ABRD|AION)[\n\d]{7}00[37]`

Comment: Please I have made a mistake in the post. I corrected it now and added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-a` option is a non-standard extension for dealing with binary files, it is not needed for text files.

```
 grep -E '^.{11}(003|007)' file.txt | grep -Ev '^(ABRD|AION)'
```

The first stage matches any line with either `003` or `007` in the twelfth through fourteenth column.

The second stage filters out removes any line starting with either `ABRD` or `AION`.

Comment: grep -Ea '^(ABRD|AION).{7}(003|007)' this doesn't remove the lines that contain (ABRD or AION).

Comment: Please I have made a mistake in the post. I corrected it now and added more details

Answer (score 1):

You really need to just read a regexp tutorial but meantime try this:

```
grep -E "^(ABRD|AION).{7}00[37]"
```

Comment: Please I have made a mistake in the post. I corrected it now and added more details